# celery tasks converts python list into strings. how to avoid this?

Tags: django, django-templates, celery, djcelery

I have an email sending tasks running in celery shared task. i am passing a python list into html template. but celery converts this list into string. but without using celery task , i am getting actual list.

Comment: Would you mind providing some code that we can take a look upon and understand your problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#serializers) you can read:

> Data transferred between clients and workers needs to be serialized, so every message in Celery has a content_type header that describes the serialization method used to encode it.
>
> The default serializer is **JSON**, but you can change this using the task_serializer setting, or for each individual task, or even per message.

As serializers, you can use also `pickle`, `yaml` and  `msgpack` but the data, MUST be serialized.

### Conclusion:

Serialization is mandatory, just keep in mind tasks will be communicating using JSON (that's your case) and de-serialize the data before using it.

Comment: is it possible to de-serialize data inside html template?

Comment: Yes, you will always have the option to go with a custom filter or tag.